# Deleting an object that spawned a thread

Tags: c++, pthreads

This seams like a silly question, but what happens when you delete an object that spawned a thread.

Is the thread destroyed instantly?

Comment: Are you talking about pthreads, `std::thread`, Windows threads, or what?

Comment: I'm willing to bet that unless you specifically destroy all threads in the object destructor, the thread will go on until it terminates.  You can get zombie threads when the process itself terminates, so I don't see why objects would be any different.

Comment: More code please, fewer words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specified in destructor, that thread should be destroyed - yes. In other case - no.